# Use bit manipulation to convert a bit from each byte in an 8-byte number to a single byte

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I have a 64-bit unsigned integer. I want to check the 6th bit of each byte and return a single byte representing those 6th bits.

The obvious, "brute force" solution is:

```
inline const unsigned char Get6thBits(unsigned long long num) {
    unsigned char byte(0);
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
        byte <<= 1;
        byte |= bool((0x20 << 8 * i) & num);
    }

    return byte;
}
```

I could unroll the loop into a bunch of concatenated `|` statements to avoid the `int` allocation, but that's still pretty ugly.

Is there a faster, more clever way to do it?  Maybe use a bitmask to get the 6th bits, `0x2020202020202020` and then somehow convert that to a byte?

Comment: Can you use any special functions such as `_pext_u64` or `_mm_movemask_epi8`?

Comment: @harold I can use anything the Visual C++ compiler can handle.  I believe that's c++ 14, but I'm not certain.

Comment: They're not in any C++ standard, they're an x86 intrinsics

Comment: @harold I believe that is fine.  I just looked up [`_mm_movemask_epi8`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s090c8fk(v=vs.90).aspx), but the documentation is a little ... minimal.

Comment: `unsigned char byte(0)` seems odd vs. `unsigned char byte = 0`. Is there any reason for that quirky notation?

Comment: @tadman Not really.  I assume the optimizer converts them to the same instructions, but technically, unoptimized, `unsigned char byte = 0` would use a two instructions: one to create the variable, and one to assign the value.  For classes/structs, this would use the `operation=` which, for some classes is deleted, so I'm just in the habit of using the notation which doesn't use the assignment operator.

Comment: @dfoverdx it doesn't really work like that, variables are not "created" (at most a stack frame will be created, but typically such integer variables are not even on the stack)

Comment: I don't know of any compiler that would do that as two operations. `unsigned char` doesn't have an initializer, it's a primitive type, so it takes zero instructions to "create the variable", all that happens is (typically) some space on the stack is allocated for it, or a register is assigned for that purpose. Initialization is another step anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `_pext_u64` is a possibility (this will work on Haswell and newer, it's very slow on Ryzen though), you could write this:

```
int extracted = _pext_u64(num, 0x2020202020202020);
```

This is a really literal way to implement it. `pext` takes a value (first argument) and a mask (second argument), at every position that the mask has a set bit it takes the corresponding bit from the value, and all bits are concatenated.

`_mm_movemask_epi8` is more widely usable, you could use it like this:

```
__m128i n = _mm_set_epi64x(0, num);
int extracted = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_slli_epi64(n, 2));
```

`pmovmskb` takes the high bit of every byte in its input vector and concatenates them. The bits we want are not the high bit of every byte, so I move them up two positions with `psllq` (of course you could shift `num` directly). The `_mm_set_epi64x` is just some way to get `num` into a vector.

Don't forget to `#include <intrin.h>`, and none of this was tested.

Codegen [seems reasonable enough](https://godbolt.org/g/QqcH6Y)

---

A weirder option is gathering the bits with a multiplication: (only slightly tested)

```
int extracted = (num & 0x2020202020202020) * 0x08102040810204 >> 56;
```

The idea here is that `num & 0x2020202020202020` only has very few bits set, so we can arrange a product that never carries into bits that we need (or indeed at all). The multiplier is constructed to do this:

```
a0000000b0000000c0000000d0000000e0000000f0000000g0000000h0000000 +
0b0000000c0000000d0000000e0000000f0000000g0000000h00000000000000 +
00c0000000d0000000e0000000f0000000g0000000h000000000000000000000 etc..
```

Then the top byte will have all the bits "compacted" together. The lower bytes actually have something like that too, but they're missing bits that would have to come from "higher" (bits can only move to the left in a multiplication).

Comment: Awesome, that looks great.  Would you mind editing your answer to include a description of what each thing does?

Comment: @dfoverdx btw I had copied your mask and assumed it was fine, but it's too short, there are only 7 bits set in it. This gave me some confusing results when I tested my code..

Comment: Oops!  I actually only need the 6th bit of the latter 7 bytes for my purposes.  I probably copied it over from my code and forgot to add the additional `20`.